# Only last iteration of loop is successfully registering my click event?

Tags: javascript, loops, events, scope

I've read several posts today on passing loop generated variables to functions and have even successfully replicated some of the issues I've seen, along with correctly implemented the fixes for those. However, there's one that I can't seem to find the answer for. I've written a loop that is adding items to a drop down list and as it does it is creating event listeners for the `click` event of those items by `id`. I've verified that the `id`'s are unique and there aren't any collisions. However, when I inspect my `Items` array, only the last item has anything associated to `onclick` and thus I believe I am encountering another scope issue.

```js
class Test {
 Items = [];
 constructor(containerID) {
   this.ContainerID = containerID;
    this.Container = document.getElementById(containerID);
  }
  AddItems(items) {
   for (let i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
     let itemID = 'li-' + this.ContainerID + '-' + this.Items.length;
      this.Container.innerHTML += '<li id="' + itemID + '">' + items[i] + '</li>';
      
      let item = document.getElementById(itemID);
      item.addEventListener("click", this.OnClick.bind(this, item));
      this.Items.push(item);
    }
  }
  OnClick(item) {
   alert(item.innerText);
  }
}

var testObject = new Test("test-container");
testObject.AddItems(["Option 1", "Option 2", "Option 3", "Option 4"]);
```

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  max-height: 200px;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
ul > li {
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #333;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<ul id="test-container"></ul>
```

The functions I'm focused on here are `AddItems` and `OnClick`. When I add an item to my collection of items, I need to bind the `click` event of that item to the `OnClick` function in which I will populate the `textbox` control with that item's `innerText`. That last part is easy enough, but for some reason, I can't even get the `click` event to register for these elements.

I've tried:

- Passing just the element's `id`.
- Passing the element.
- Using `var` instead of `let`.

Everything I've tried has resulted in only the last item raising the click event. I've encountered and resolved this same issue outside of the current context and had no issues. Even the most popular solution I've found hasn't been able to resolve this:

```
  AddItems(items) {
    for (let i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
        (function(instance, _i) {
            let itemID = 'li-' + instance.ContainerID + '-' + instance.Items.length;
        instance.Container.innerHTML += '<li id="' + itemID + '">' + items[_i] + '</li>';

        let item = document.getElementById(itemID);
        item.addEventListener("click", instance.OnClick.bind(instance, item));
        instance.Items.push(item);
      })(this, i);
    }
  }
```

This still results in only the last item having a registered `click` event.

---

### UPDATE

Oddly enough, if I make a secondary call to `AddItems` in my implementation code, the very last item to be added to the `Items` array is still the only item with a `click` event registered. I even added a `setTimeout` to see if maybe `JavaScript` was combining my calls, and still got the same result.

```
var testObject = new Test("test-container");
testObject.AddItems(["Option 1", "Option 2", "Option 3", "Option 4"]);
setTimeout(function() {
    testObject.AddItems(["Option 5", "Option 6", "Option 7", "Option 8"]);
}, 5000);
```

---

How do I pass my loop-scoped variable to a bound `function` for the `click` event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you concatenate the `innerHTML` property of `Container`, you are replacing the entire contents of the DOM element, thus losing any already bound events. You either bind events when you're done messing with `innerHTML` of `Container` (which would be a workaround, but still bad) or you simply use the proper method: `appendChild`:

```js
class Test {
  Items = [];
  constructor(containerID) {
    this.ContainerID = containerID;
    this.Container = document.getElementById(containerID);
  }
  AddItems(items) {
    let itemID, item;
    for (let i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
      itemID = 'li-' + this.ContainerID + '-' + this.Items.length;
      item = document.createElement('li');
      item.id = itemID;
      item.innerHTML = items[i];
      this.Container.appendChild(item);
      item.addEventListener("click", this.OnClick.bind(this, item))
      this.Items.push(item);
    }
  }
  OnClick(item) {
    alert(item.innerText);
  }
}

var testObject = new Test("test-container");
testObject.AddItems(["Option 1", "Option 2", "Option 3", "Option 4"]);
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  max-height: 200px;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

ul>li {
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #333;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<ul id="test-container"></ul>
```

---

Edit: Not directly related, but I thought it should be mentioned, for educational purposes: binding one event per child should be avoided, when possible, because:

- it's heavier (noticeable when dealing with large amounts of children)
- if you update the children dynamically, you don't have an API to get the children which do not have a particular binding; and forgetting to bind the new members immediately after you appended them is an easy to make mistake

But you can take advantage of event bubbling: you bind only one event on the parent. This will work even on children who are not present in DOM when you make the binding. Your updated example:

```js
class Test {
  Items = [];
  constructor(id) {
    this.Container = document.getElementById(id);
    this.Container.addEventListener("click", this.OnClick.bind(this));
  }
  AddItems(items) {
    let item;
    for (let i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
      item = document.createElement("li");
      item.id = `li-${this.Container.id}-${this.Items.length}`;
      item.innerHTML = items[i];
      this.Container.appendChild(item);
      this.Items.push(item);
    }
  }
  OnClick(event) {
    const item = event.target.closest(`#${this.Container.id} li`);
    if (item) {
      alert(item.innerText);
    }
  }
}

const testObject = new Test("test-container");
testObject.AddItems(["Option 1", "Option 2", "Option 3", "Option 4"]);
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  max-height: 200px;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

ul>li {
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #333;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<ul id="test-container"></ul>
```

As you can see, even though the binding is done in `constructor`, which happens before you're adding the `<li>`s, it works and it will keep working if you delete them and add others. And it's only one binding, which works for all present and future children.

Note I changed the `OnClick` method, no longer overwriting the default param (which is the `event`) and using it to select the `<li>` when the method is called.

Comment: Welcome. If you ever want to remove all events from a page `document.body.innerHTML +='';` will do.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you're only getting one listener, or perhaps you have multiple listeners that are all acting on the same item, instead of each item? Your example is too complicated to get working in a snippet, so you might have some difficulty in getting an answer. But, I suspect it is your `this` reference, which will not be set to what you expect when a click handler is executed.

You have two AddItems functions. The first one, seemed to misuse the `this` parameter but the last one seemed to capture it successfully as `ddl`. You can inspect each item directly in the browser devtools to see if each one has a unique listener. If so, you should restate your question (and try to get a smaller example if you're not having luck getting answers).

Comment: I've updated my code snippet to remove everything I can to get the issue to replicate properly. It is indeed only one event, on just the last element. I believe this is due to the item being overwritten with every iteration of the loop.

Comment: You have an items array, and you have a this.Items array. You are always generating an ID of this.Items.length, but I can't tell if that array is changing. Did you mean `let itemID = "li-dd-" + this.ContainerID + "-" + i` instead?

Comment: No, because you can make n number of calls to add items, so the most recent call should be adding the id as the next id available; this creates the id in a 0-n fashion.

Comment: If it helps, make an additional call to add items with another array (even one item will work). I’m going to see what that does to the event registration and update my post while I’m at it.

Comment: Well, I updated the snippet but turns out I have an error with running the entire thing on mobile. I’ll look at it again when I get home.

Comment: So not what I expected to happen... I expected two items in my list to have click events, the last one from the first add, and the last one from the second add. This was not the case, and only the very last one had a click event. :/ Perhaps JavaScript chained my back to back calls together and treated it as one. I'll try with a `setTimeout`.